# Check if database is connected on localhost:9200 with node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using a nodejs server in local. This application is connected to a mongodb on port localhost:9200.

I would like to know if there is a possiblity to check the connection to the database at the beginning of my node server in the code so that I don't have to wait until the node try to fecth something from the server to find out that there is no connection

Something like this :

```
checkConnection('localhost:9200', (err) => {
  if (err)
      console.log('can't connect to database')
  else
       console.log('database connected')
}
```

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: What ORM do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I supose that you are using mongoose to manage you Mongo database. In this case you could try with this sentence:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// Database connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:9200/<name of your database>')
.then(() => {
    console.log("Database conection Ok");
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

You could also start your server if your database is running correctly, you could try with this sentence:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let app = require('./app');
let port = 3800;

// Database connection
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:9200/<name of your database>')
.then(() => {
    console.log("Database conection Ok");
    // Server creation
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log("Server running in http://localhost:3800");
    });
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```